# Reload QWebView with pyqt

Tags: qt, pyqt, qwebview

maybe this is a trivial question but I cannot solve it.

I have an application with a QWebView that loads a local html file. I'm happy with it, but I need to implement a button that works exactly as the right click -> reload function within the webview itself.

In the documentation I see that there is the `reload` function, but even if I don't get any errors it seems not working (nothing happens).

This is the method called when pushing the button. The first time it works well, the QWebView is loaded correctly with the local html file, while the other times (other plots created and same `self.plot_path` file overwritten) I have to manually right click and reload the view.

```
.....
def reloadView(self):
    self.plot_path = "/tmp/tmp_plot.html"
    self.layoutw = QVBoxLayout()
    self.plot_qview.setLayout(self.layoutw)
    plot_url = QUrl.fromLocalFile(self.plot_path)
    self.plot_view = QWebView()
    self.plot_view.load(plot_url)
    self.layoutw.addWidget(self.plot_view)
    self.plot_view.reload()
    .....
```

I cannot figure out if I have to *destroy* the view of create other `html` local file or if I am missing something.

Comment: You should not need to recreate the layout and `QWebView` every time if all you want to do is reload the document.

Comment: perfect get it! I put the layout and the `QWebView` in the init function and now the reloading works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might try this as well.

```
view->settings()->setObjectCacheCapacities(0,0,0);
```

I had a similar issue with changed file content not being recognized
by the reload() method/slot.